# Name of the user not getting displayed in python code

Tags: python, html, web

I have made a signup page using python. Following is the link to the code :

[Signup Page Code](http://ideone.com/HcQ1Op)

As soon as a user signs up, he should be redirected to `/welcome` which says :

```
Welcome user
```

But I cannot display it by the above mentioned code.

Whereas when I write

```
self.redirect('/welcome?username = '+user)
```

I get redirected to a page which says

```
Welcome user
```

Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
self.redirect('/welcome?username=' + user) #no whitespaces in the url
```

you are adding to the url a GET parameter(of the type name=value), in your case username=user.
So, when your welcomeHandler class handles the get request:

```
username=self.request.get('username')
```

it sets the username to the value of the GET parameter in the url with the name 'username' (username = user) and your welcome message is correctly displayed.
If you:

```
self.redirect('/welcome')
```

there are no GET parameters in the url and username is set to the default empty string and just Welcome is displayed.

Check [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass#Request_get) the Request documentation.

Comment: So, what should I do to print the username in the welcome page?

Comment: But I dont want the username in the URL.

Comment: Then you need to store the user in a database and retrieve the user name in the welcome page using cookies